# test FirebaseFirestore with JUnit using await, error

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockk

I am using:

```
     val data = firestore.collection("add").document("departament").collection("anuncios").document(id).get()
            .await() 
return data.toObject(Anuncios::class.java)
```

and in my test I wrote like this:

```
    @Test
    fun `Get Add by id correct, should return data`() = runBlockingTest {
        //GIVEN

        coEvery {
            firestore.collection("add").document("departament").collection("anuncios")
                .document("01sm3zv3aCzGrWX3ycPT").get()
        } returns dataTask


        // WHEN
        adRepository.getAnuncioId("01sm3zv3aCzGrWX3ycPT").apply {
            // THEN
            Truth.assertThat(this).isEqualTo(Anuncios())
            coVerify(exactly = 1) {
                firestore.collection("add").document("departament").collection("anuncios")
                    .document("01sm3zv3aCzGrWX3ycPT").get().await()
            }
            verify(exactly = 1) { datoSnap.toObject(Anuncios::class.java)!! }
        }
    }
```

the error throws me:

no answer found for: Task(#6).isComplete()

There is a problem with the await, but I don't know how to do it, I am new to unit test

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), you can't run a test and wait for a real response, you have to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
mockkStatic("kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.TasksKt")
```

since this mocks the functions that are required